# How constrain a Locator to follow a list of points inside Manipulate?

Tags: manipulate, locator

I would like position two locators on discrete positions which are list's elements and represent a list of point's coordinates. 
I've ani image and on this I've detected ten circle shape. Now I'd like evaluate the mutual distancnces among circle's centroids using Locator and EuclideanDistance inside Manipulate.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post a minimal example of what you have tried so far and what does not work?

Comment: Manipulate[
 Graphics[Line[{p, q}], PlotRange -> 2], {{p, List[[1]]}, 
  List[[2 ;;]], Locator}, {{q, List[[1]]}, List[[2 ;;]], Locator}]

Comment: You should edit your question and describe your problem, not put the example in a comment. Be as precise as you can, only then people will be able to help you.

Comment: I want to move a locator on an image;  this locator mustn't change position continuosly but follows a list of points.

Comment: You can attach EventHandler to Points too.

Comment: On second thought, if you have the centroid positions as a list of coordinates, just generate all the possible pairs (`Subsets[yourlist, {2}]`), then apply `EuclideanDistance` to each pair.

Comment: Regarding your problem as formulated, however, perhaps [`ClickPane`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClickPane.html) or [`LocatorPane`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LocatorPane.html) and `Dynamic` might be a more appropriate choice than a `Locator` within `Manipulate`; you might find inspiration in the examples shown in that documentation page.